# Need to redraw a map with new data (in conjunction with CartoDB.js)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I seem to be having some trouble with reinitializing a Leaflet map object. I am running an init() function that starts by initializing a map, adding a tilelayer and layer with polygons, and then adding sublayers which color the polygons according to a ST_Intersects query. The issue is that this function is tied to an AJAX call that is caused by a click event but does not update the data according to the new parameters sent to the map. I don't think I am explaining this very well, so here is a bit of my code:

```
success: function(data) {

                init(data);
}



function init(data){
  // initiate leaflet map
  alert("start");
  var map = L.map('cartodb-map').setView([40.750028, -73.926768], 11);
  alert("map made");

//create sublayers, etc
}
```

What happens is that the first time init is run, both 'start' and 'map made' alerts work, and the map is made according to the data. Any further calls to init simply alerts with "start" and "map made" is never alerted so I believe the problem is with reinitializing the leaflet map. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the problem without seeing more of your code, but you could try calling map.remove(); the second time around.  So:

```
if (map) {
  map.remove();
  // add in new map initialization here
} else {
  var map = ...
}
```